# how to inject webapp resource using relative path in spring

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, relative-path

I have a bean which im trying to pass a relative path at web application startup.  It works for an absolute path (running tomcat within eclipse) such as (**C:/dev/workspace/project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resource/**)

However when  I try to pass it a relative path such as **WEB-INF/my_resource/** it says cannot find the location **C:/dev/eclipse/WEB-INF/my_resource/** probably because tomcat is running within eclipse.  How can I make this path relative so that it will be always picked up from whatever webcontainer is running it no matter the location of the webapp?

Ive read in place to use the servletconfig.getRelativePath(/) but neither know how to obtain the servlet config from within my bean or even if this is the right thing to do in Spring... Please help

The source code for my bean class and bean configuration xml can be found below

```
public class SuggestionIndexSearcher extends IndexSearcher {

private String indexSearcherType;

public SuggestionIndexSearcher(String type, String path){
    super(path);
    this.indexSearcherType = type;
}
...
}
```

The bean is defined in teh beans xml as...

```
    <bean id="KMSearcherBean" class="com.hp.it.km.search.web.suggestion.SuggestionIndexSearcher">
      <constructor-arg index="0" value="KMSearcher" />
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="WEB-INF/resource/keyword" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What is `IndexSearcher`, and what does it do with `path`?  It seems the problem is with how that handles that String.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Maybe I was unclear... This could be any class, its irrelevant.  My problem is not what is happening after it enters the class nor what the class extends or does with the string.   What I am asking is what code can I add, before super() is called, to transform path="/WEB-INF/my_resource/" into path=<web app location>"/WEB-INF/my_resource/ where <web app location>=is the file system location of the webapp within tomcat or weblogic or whatever application server that the webapp may happen to run within. i.e. I need to find out what <web app location> is?

Comment: fixed by simply changing String to Resource. cheers Skaffman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your change your bean to take `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` ([javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)) instead of `String`, then Spring will automagically coerce your path into the appropriate type of `Resource`. When running inside a servlet container, Spring will generally pick `ServletContextResource`, in which the path becomes relative to the webapp root (so `WEB-INF/my_resource/` should work as you expect).

How your code chooses to handle `Resource` depends what you want to do with it, obviously.

No change is required in your XML config, just keep passing the path string as before. See [the Spring manual for a wider description of resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Didn't think it would be that easy.  I'm coming around to this spring stuff. Cheers skaffman

Answer (score 0):

Change the argument type from String to Resource - spring will then do the conversion and give you the resource object which you can process.  You should be using an XMLWebApplicationContext (which is the default if the context is being created by the ContextLoaderListener or DispatcherServlet).

Take a look at this [page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/resources.html) for more details.